# Can ultrasonic distance sensor get good readings for a passing object?

Tags: sensors

I am working on a project where I laid 5 Ultrasonic distance sensors in a string on a rigid wood plank that lays on the ground and points all the sensors upward behind the guy with the bat.

When the pitcher pitches the ball and the ball goes over the sensors, the sensors have to detect the passing ball and compute their distance from the ground to have an idea whether the ball passed within the strike zone.

I ran into the following issues

Issue #1: The ultrasonic distance sensor was giving a lot of "noise", the pulse in was giving some 10-15 different values all the time even when it's just statically placed on the table while looking at the ceiling. Which was computing 15 different distances to the ceiling some of them were far off from the others.

I solved issue #1 by using a "initialization" routine where for first 10 seconds the sensor collects those noises and adds them to an array so it can ignore them later. All good.

Issue #2: The sensors failed to detect a fast moving ball, in fact I had to pass the ball super slow like 2 centimeters per seconds for it to detect it, otherwise there was no reading (may be something wrong with my code).

Here are my questions

1. Is ultrasonic distance sensor capable of detecting a fast moving object? My initial assessment with a simple `pulseIn` did show me something that sounded meaningful but that may have been just the noise throwing me off.
2. What other type of sensors can be good for this type of problems?

Here is my code. My apologies if this ridiculously long and rough sketch is not easy to read.

```
#include "stdio.h"

const int PIN_TRIG = 9;
const int PIN_ECHO = 10;
const int PIN_WARN = 11;

long distance;
int duration;
long oldDistance;

 int min = 1024;
unsigned int max = 0;
int totalUniques[100];

unsigned int cycles = 0;
bool warnOn = false;
unsigned int warnTime = 0;

bool uniqueCollected = false;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 pinMode(PIN_TRIG, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(PIN_ECHO, INPUT);
 pinMode(PIN_WARN, OUTPUT);
 InitializeUniques();

 Serial.begin(9600);



  digitalWrite(PIN_WARN, HIGH);
  warnOn = true;
}

void loop() {

  digitalWrite(PIN_TRIG, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(PIN_TRIG, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15);
  digitalWrite(PIN_TRIG, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(PIN_ECHO, HIGH);
  distance = duration*0.034/2;

  if (distance < min && distance != 0) 
  {
    min = distance;
  }

  if (distance > max)
  {
    max = distance;
  }

 if (uniqueCollected == false)
 {
  int st = AddUnique(distance);

  printWithLabel("Adding unique", distance, "Total Unique Status", st);
  if (cycles > 1000)
  {
    PrintAllUniques();
    uniqueCollected = true;

    warnOn = false;
    digitalWrite(PIN_WARN, LOW);
    warnTime = millis();
  }
  else 
  {
    cycles++;
  }
 }

  if (warnOn == true && uniqueCollected == true)
  {
    auto t = millis();
    if (abs(t - warnTime) > 10000)
    {
      digitalWrite(PIN_WARN, LOW);
      warnOn = false;
    }
  }

  if (distance > 150)
  {
    AddUnique(distance);
  }
  if (warnOn == false && uniqueCollected == true && FoundInUniques(distance) == false)
  {
    PrintAllUniques();
    printWithLabel("distance", distance);
    warnOn = false;
    digitalWrite(PIN_WARN, HIGH);
    delay(10000);

    digitalWrite(PIN_WARN, LOW);
   // warnTime = millis();
  }

  if (oldDistance < 0 && distance > 0 && distance < 150) 
  {
   // printDistances(1);
  }
  else if (abs(oldDistance - distance) > 30)
  {
  //  printDistances(2);
  }

  oldDistance = distance;

 // Serial.print("Distance: ");
  //Serial.println(distance);


}


void printDistances(int caller)
{

    Serial.print("Something detected in the way");
    Serial.print(caller);
    Serial.print(" old : ");
    Serial.print(oldDistance);
    Serial.print(" new : ");
    Serial.println(distance);
}
void printWithLabel(char* label, int value)
{
   Serial.print(label);
   Serial.print(": ");
   Serial.println(value);
}
void printWithLabel(char* label1, int value1, char* label2, int value2)
{
   Serial.print(label1);
   Serial.print(": ");
   Serial.println(value1);
   Serial.print(", ");
   Serial.print(label2);
   Serial.print(": ");
   Serial.println(value2);
}
int AddUnique(int value)
{

  if (value == 0)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    if (abs(totalUniques[i] - value) <= 3 || totalUniques[i] == 0)
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (i >= 100)
  {
    return -2;
  } 
  else if (totalUniques[i] == 0)
  {
    totalUniques[i] = value;
    return i + 1;
  }
  return CountTotalUniques();
}

void InitializeUniques()
{
  for (int i=0;i<100;i++) totalUniques[i]=0;
}

int CountTotalUniques() 
{
  for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    if (totalUniques[i] == 0)
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

void PrintAllUniques() 
{
  Serial.print("Unique Values :");

  for (int i=0;i<100 && totalUniques[i] != 0;i++)
  {
    Serial.print(totalUniques[i]);
    if (i < 99)
    {
       Serial.print(", ");
    }
  }

  Serial.println(" ");
}

bool FoundInUniques(int value)
{
  if (value == 0)
  {
    return true;
  }

  for (int i=0;i<100 && totalUniques[i] != 0;i++)
  {
    if (abs(totalUniques[i] - value) <= 3)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't sound very feasible.  In order for it to work you'd have to fire the ping sensor at exactly the right millisecond so that the sound meets the ball directly above the sensor.   Whatever means you use to detect the ball in order to fire the sensor would probably itself be a better option for locating the ball.

Comment: @Delta_G What's the harm in firing the sensor every few microseconds? It can't miss the ball unless Nolan Ryan is pitching. Correct?

Comment: Because the sensor can't fire that fast.  How high is the ball above the sensor?  How long does it take sound to go that far?  How fast is the ball moving?  How long will it be in the spot above the sensor?

Comment: Sound travels at around 1100 feet per second.  So that gets us about 1.1 feet per millisecond.  If the ball is shoulder high then we've got something on the order of 10ms for the round trip before we can safely say we didn't see the ball.  And that's assuming nothing misses high.  So once every ten or fifteen milliseconds you can fire the sensor.    If we're in the little league throwing 60mph then we're at 88 ft/s.  That's 11ms to cross a 1 foot section.   You see where we're going?  That's on the same order as your cycle time for the sensor.  You can't fire fast enough.

Comment: @Delta_G "So once every ten or fifteen milliseconds you can fire the sensor", did you mean Microseconds? I am firing every few microseconds.

Comment: @fahadash No, he ment milliseconds. It is irrelevant how fast you create a trigger pulse on the Arduino. It needs 10ms to receive the echo of trigger pulse. You need to wait for the echo to arrive, before firing the next pulse, or you will get false readings, because the echo of the first pulse is still to come (also most likely your sensor simply cannot trigger a new pulse before the current pulse is finished

Comment: you would be better off detecting the breaking of two planes a know distance apart, and measuring the time between breaks.

Comment: If you are firing the pulse every few microseconds and it takes 10ms for the pulse to travel to the ball and back, how will you know which pulse hit the ball?  How will you calculate distance if you don't know which pulse it was?